# NodeLabel Parameter Plugin not working with pipelines

Tags: jenkins, plugins

My current setup is not working well with the NodeLabel Parameter Plugin and I am wondering if I am missing something, I find the documentation at https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin incomplete (e.g. it is missing any info on node configuration when using label restriction).

My setup :
- nodes are setup with the options : 1) only build job with label expressions matching this node 2) label field set to 'mytest'
- pipeline definition in jenkins gui set with the following option checked 'This project is parameterized', I have added the label default value to 'mytest'. I kept the default name to 'executor label' based on the documentation (guessing this is not relevant though)

Result : the job gets stuck, output below

> [Pipeline] node  [...all my agents listed here] is reserved for jobs with matching label

I am using a shared library for my pipeline, I also have tried to add the label in the node object :

> node{        label 'mytest' }

same issue. I m not finding much help online - again I am surprised by the lack of details in the Jenkins plugin documentation.

Any suggestion? thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand exactly what you're trying to do, but have you tried just selecting a node with `node('mytest') { ... }` without using the parameterized version with that plugin and see if that will build?  If not, it might point to an issue in the node setup, rather than your labels.

Comment: Does not work, I ve tried setting the node as 'use this node as much as possible' or  'only build [..] with label expression', either way the nodes are not picking the job.

Comment: is there a view in Jenkins where I can see the reason why some jobs are incompatible with specific nodes?

Comment: "I'm not sure that I understand exactly what you're trying to do" => set some labels on jobs and nodes to create pools of build agents allocated for certain categories of jobs exclusively.

Comment: Right, but I wasn't sure if you actually needed to specify the type of node in a parameter, or whether it was pretty much fixed (so that every time you're running your build, you'll always choose `mytest`, or whether you needed it parameterized).  If it's always fixed by the type of job, you can just use the syntax that I put in before without using that plugin.  Can you screenshot your node labels configuration?

Comment: I uninstalled the NodeLabel Parameter plugin, removed all labels everywhere and now none of my nodes are picking the jobs. I don t think the screenshot can help, it s basic setup ''use this node as much as possible' , no labels, using java web start.

Comment: Before, did you have `mytest` in your labels in the node configuration?  I have a Jenkins setup without that plugin, and simply putting a label in my node configuration (in my case, `windows-slave`) allows my `node('windows-slave')` jobs to run properly on nodes that have that label.  So, I don't have a great idea of why it's not working for you.

Comment: I did not try without the plugin NodeLabel unf. Now after installing and uninstalling the plugin I seem to have all nodes setup so a label match is expected. (no matter what I specify in my nodes configuration!).

Comment: I ve tried without the plugin NodeLabel today, and no improvement. A node labeled with 'x' will not pick pipeline with ' label 'x' '. All my jobs are stuck with "pending—master is offline". I see you are able to get this working on your end, could tell me confirm you node setup : I have "Use this node as much as possible", "java web start" , "Executors : 1"